# No tests found with test runner JUnit 4

Tags: java, testing, junit, case

I have a JUnit test case that I am trying to use but it is giving me the error "No tests found with test runner JUnit 4". Yes, I have looked at that other one on here that asks the same thing but that does not work for me. My tests are already named by starting with "test"

Does anyone know how to fix this? Here is my test class

```
package testing;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class cubeTest {


    public void testCube(){
        shape3D.Cube cube = new shape3D.Cube(2);
        assertTrue(cube.getVolume() == 8);
        assertTrue(cube.getSurfaceArea() == 24);
    }
    public void testCube1(){
        shape3D.Cube cube = new shape3D.Cube(4);
        assertTrue(cube.calculateVolume() == 64);
        assertTrue(cube.calculateSurfaceArea() == 96);
    }
    public void testCube2(){
        shape3D.Cube cube = new shape3D.Cube(3);
        assertTrue(cube.getVolume() == 27);
        assertTrue(cube.calculateSurfaceArea() == 54);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to add annotations to your suite. Do:

```
    public class cubeTest {

            @Test
        public void testCube(){
            shape3D.Cube cube = new shape3D.Cube(2);
            assertTrue(cube.getVolume() == 8);
            assertTrue(cube.getSurfaceArea() == 24);
        }
        @Test
        public void testCube1(){
            shape3D.Cube cube = new shape3D.Cube(4);
            assertTrue(cube.calculateVolume() == 64);
            assertTrue(cube.calculateSurfaceArea() == 96);
        }
        @Test
        public void testCube2(){
            shape3D.Cube cube = new shape3D.Cube(3);
            assertTrue(cube.getVolume() == 27);
            assertTrue(cube.calculateSurfaceArea() == 54);
        }


    }
```

You might also want to set up `setUp` and `tearDown` methods as well. If you do, add the `@Before` & `@After` to those methods.

Comment: You need to use `@Test`, not `@test`